# SP2010 OOB Approval Workflow Error - Failed on start

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow, approval-process, workflow-tasks-list

In our SharePoint 2010 on premise farm, we have a document library which has 6 OOB approval workflows.

All the workflows are triggered manually and all these workflows have been working fine for years.

Suddenly from mid of April, all the workflows are erroring with message "Failed on start" and doesn't get started.

I republished all the workflows but still get the same error. Not sure how to troubleshoot further and resolve the issue.

Below is the error message in Workflow history:

[image]

This issue is occurring in all site collections. Its occurring even in new site collections. Restarted the "Workflow" site collection feature but still get the same error.

Please Note: SharePoint Designer workflows are working fine.

Are there any Windows Server services(Like SharePoint Timer Administration Service) that i need to restart that may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was because of installing KB4507004 and KB4532945. Same issue as this article

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first check the ULS log to find error message which may be related to this issue. Also please test with newly created OOB approval workflow and see if this works.

Comment: ULS Logs also sow the same error message . I created a new library and created a new workflow but still get the same error

Comment: @George what dose the error message say?

Comment: I think the issue was with the latest security update installed on the server. We face the same error as described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update

Comment: @George Does the resolution help?